# Anylogic: How to model setup times (tool change) in ResourcePool based on a parameter of the agent?

Tags: model, simulation, production, anylogic

Since I got great help with the last question and didn't find any helpful tips in the help/tutorials, I'll try again :)
Simplified situation is:

- Production of different product variants (Agent `Product` with parameter `productID`)
- Production line with 4 stations (modelled as `service`); each station has 2 machines (modelled as `ResourcePool`)
- When changing the product variant, the machines must be retooled.

My idea is to record the machine status as variable/parameter (`MachineStatus`). When a resource unit is seized (code executed "*on seize*"), then it is compared whether `productID` = `machineStatus`. If they are equal, then no delay, if they are different, then interrupt for a certain time. However, I have two or three problems:

- How can I assign a **variable `MachineStatus` to a uni**t of ResourcePool? Especially if I have 2 machines in a resource pool and therefore separate MachineStatus?
- I tried to use self.timeout to model the **interruption**, but this leads to errors.
- Or, in general; is this approach effective or have I overlooked something essential?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone is interested in how I solved the problem (a little bit different from my idea):

- Define a parameter `MachineStatus` and a function "RetoolingTime"
- Value of `DelayTime` of my service block:

> MachineStatus.equals(agent.productID) ? 30 : 30 + RetoolingTime(agent.productID, RetoolingTime)

Note that 30s is my normal processing time and in case I have to retool, there is an additional retooling-time, which is calculated by the function.

To get the retooling-time I wrote the code into the function body of the function `RetoolingTime`:

> [Code of RetoolingTime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQCFI.png)